# How do I add a Facebook Subscribe button to my website?

Tags: facebook, like

So the Facebook Subscribe button is pretty great for those who want to maintain their social life and start building a public persona, and is a great alternative to pages for those people.

But switching to this alternative loses the brilliant one-click Like button for websites.

Do Facebook offer a solution which allows you to add a subscribe button for your website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy, facebook offer a generator here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/ essentially it's a like button with different text.

Comment: I don't think this was available when I originally asked the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you mean. The "Facebook Authentication" button is totally different from the like/share button and not an alternative.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

I personally have both on my website, you can also add Facebook comments to posts linked to share/posts with optional facebook registration for your guests.